# Iterations With Unequal Steps

Tags: python, iteration

A current project requires that I create a list of numbers in unequal steps and in groups.
I.e. I need the steps to be say, 3, then 5, 7, 3, 12, 9, 4, 8. That would be group one. The next group continues but starts over at the beginning of the steps. The resulting steps are used in an expression to produce the desired series of numbers.

I created the below code using "starmap," "lambda"--thanks to [this](http://pymotw.com/2/itertools/) great tutorial on advanced iterations. Does anyone know of a better way to iterate or other, in unequal steps?

Note: The values of the resulting number series is not important, only the steps.

The working code:

```
from itertools import *
h = 0 ## Sets first group
for i in range (4): ## Number of groups to produce
    values = [(6, h, 2), (6, h, 4), (6, h, 6), (6, h, 8), (6, h, 10), (6, h, 12), (6, h, 14), (6, h, 16)]
    for j in starmap(lambda x,y, z:(x, y, z, (x * y) + z), values):
        print '(%d * %d) + %d = %d' % j
    print("")
    h += 5 ## Increments by 5 for each group
```

Comment: What is the step that's varying in your code?

Comment: I don't quite catch your meaning. This code shows a very special case, and it's good enough. But I think you are finding a more general solution, aren't you?

Comment: Yes. I was just curious as to what others thought and if they had a better way. Someone did post what I think is a better, or at least more succinct way, but then he removed it. I modded it and here is the raw code:    steps = [3,5,7,3,12,9,4,8]
    for i in xrange(4): ## a bit more efficient than range, even though doesn't matter here
        for j in steps:
            print j + (3 * i)
        print("")

Comment: I'm sure I'm just being dense -- long week -- but I don't see how 3,5,7,3,12,9,4,8 has any connection with the numbers your working code produces.  I also don't know if those numbers are entirely random or if there's a pattern I can't see.

Comment: The idea is to be able to step or iterate in unequal steps so as to generate a series of numbers based on a grouping of those steps.

Comment: By `unequal steps`, do you mean with no pattern, as in `random`? You could use list comprehension on `values` like so if you just want to simplify.  `values = [(6, h, x) for x in [3,5,7,3,12,9,4,8]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's unclear to me what the desired roll of something like `[3,5,7,3,12,9,4,8]` should be in reference to the code block provided, I'll provide some alternate approaches to the code given.

Instead of creating and overwriting `values` in every loop, you could create the entire list and iterate with a generator over the necessary referencing pattern.

```
e = 2
f = 8
g = 4
h = 5
values = [(6, x, y) for x in xrange(0, g * h, h) for y in xrange(e, f * e + 1, e)]
gen = (values[((x + 1) * f) - f:(x + 1) * f] for x in xrange(g))
for i in gen:
    for j in starmap(lambda x, y, z:(x, y, z, (x * y) + z), i):
        print('(%d * %d) + %d = %d' % j)

    print('')
```

Or if you know where to start with `h` (0), how much to increment by (5), and how many total groups (4), you can iterate over a range and use list comprehension to assign `values`.

```
h = 5
for i in xrange(0, 4 * h, h):
    values = [(6, i, x) for x in xrange(2, 17, 2)]
    for j in starmap(lambda x, y, z:(x, y, z, (x * y) + z), values):
        print('(%d * %d) + %d = %d' % j)

    print('')
```